# MySQL rating table optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a RatingTable in MySQL:
player_id INT, game_type INT, rating INT
There are 5 different game types (e.g. chess, checks, go, etc.)
Higher rating in game is better
I want to get top 10 player_id with highest TOTAL rating. Total rating = sum of all ratings for all game types.
I can solve it like this:

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(rating) as TotalRating 
FROM RatingTable 
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY TotalRating DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But my concern is that it will take to much memory&cpu if there're 10 million players with 5 different game types. It will sum all ratings for all 10mln players and then sort it. How can I optimize it?

Comment: This looks good to me. Make sure you add indexes.

Comment: this is what you need and there's no cost effective way to do it at run time, generate mock data for predicted number of records and execute the query to see what the out come is, if this doesn't work you will have to create a mapping table for user and corresponding sum(rating) that way you will not have to compute at run time.

Comment: Let's approach it from a different angle.  How many times per day do you run that query?  How many times a day is some rating changed?